# Why does dreamweaver show an error on this line when the code is valid

Tags: php, dreamweaver

Why does Dreamweaver show a red error on this line

```
<?php $pt=$test->Terms()['Terms'];?>
```

The line is perfectly valid and runs, and does what it is supposed to do, and yet dreamweaver insists that it is an error.

I have a function returning a named array you see, and it works fine on the page.

Comment: A fault in the DW syntax checker. Or maybe an old DW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly accessing an array key of a function result. Array dereferencing of function results was implemented in PHP 5.4. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

I'd guess that the syntax checking of Dreamweaver uses a version of PHP < 5.4.

Comment: I am using dreamweaver cs6

Comment: You are correct. I finally found this link https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1039164

Answer (score -1):

You should check array key existence before referencing to it

Comment: It is ok I do the check in my function before returning the array. So even though there is no check visiable it is checked

Comment: I meant, you should do it in code. That's what IDE probably warns you about

Comment: Yes in my function terms it checks if the return value is null or empty and returns an empty string array if that is the case. So it will always return something valid outside the function so I don't need to check there.

Comment: IDE doesn't know about your approach then. It's kind of common practice as array structure could not be declared for client code therefore client code could not rely on that key existence without checks.

I guess if you would like to stick with your approach your only option is to disable this inspection using IDE settings.

Comment: Or upgrade my Dreamweaver. Thanks for the reply anyway